# Can you use an android device as a wireless adapter for kali linux?

Tags: wifi, wireless, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I am experimenting with Kali Linux. I set up Kali in Virtual Box on a mac. I realized that to do WPA/WPA2 cracking I would need a wireless adapter. Before running out to buy one I thought that I might be able to use the usb tethering capabilities of an android phone (Galaxy S4) as a wireless adapter. I managed to get wifi through the phone but I still can't get airodump-ng wlan0mon to give any data.

I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to do this and if so how would I set up my phone as a wireless adapter for Kali. I'm not sure if I need to install any drivers and I wouldn't even know which to install since I don't know what wireless card is in S4s.

Comment: The use of a phone as a wifi adapter for a VM has nothing to do with security, even if the reason you want to use it is for a security related VM.

Comment: No ! And offtopic

Answer (score 2):

No, you need a separate wireless card with a chipset that supports monitor mode. (i.e. Alfa, TPlink).

Here is a good resource that shows the [Alfa nics BHIS uses.](https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/?p=5703)